# Rails - How to reference the current and next record together

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ancestry

How do I Loop through a record set and pass the current record, record1 and still be able to reference the next record in the same operation?

```
        <% menu_item.children.menu.each do |record1| %>
            <%= wrap_submenu(record1) %>
            <%= wrap_submenu_a(record2) %>
        <% end %>
```

I am using the ancestry gem

Answer (score 1):

You could use each_cons(2) :

```
   (1..10).each_cons(2){|a,b| puts a;puts b; puts "----"}
    =>
    1
    2
    ----
    2
    3
    ----
    3
    4
    ----
    4
    5
    ----
    5
    6
    ----
    6
    7
    ----
    7
    8
    ----
    8
    9
    ----
    9
    10
    ----
```

So in your case :

```
menu_item.children.menu.each_cons(2) do |record1,record2|
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very clean but you can use `each_with_index` with last element iteration consideration